# Hints for recursive sequence problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, problem-solving, recursion, pattern-recognition

I am working on this problem:

> [image]

I would just like a hint if possible. This is what I've done so far:

$1)$ Calculated the sequence to more terms (if I didn't make a mistake): $2, 7, 1, 4, 7, 4, 2, 8, 2, 8, 8, 1, 6, 1, 6, 1, 6, 6,4, 8, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 6, 2, 4, 3, 2.$

$2)$ I wrote the positions of the first few $6's$: $13, 15, 17, 18, 21,22,23,24,25,27,35,37, 39$

I couldn't find a pattern anywhere.

**EDIT:** I eventually arrived at the same approach that Anatoly gave in his answer (that is, looking for a self-reproducing chunk). However, I couldn't find any such chunk. I am wondering what is the best way to find such a chunk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to look for a pattern of digits that occur in a cyclic manner and that contain the digit $6$. For example, if the sequence $888$ occurs, it begets as successive sequences $6464 \,$, $2424...\, $, $888\,$. So if we demonstrate that a triple $888$ occurs, it necessarily  implies that there are infinite $6$ in the whole sequence.

Actually the triple $888\,$ occurs: you have already noted that the sequence contains $636\,$, which begets $1818\,$, which in turn begets  $888\,$.

Comment: Ah I was just working on the problem and came up with this idea myself but couldn't find any sort of repeating chunk, let alone one containing $6's$. But I have a question, how did you find $888$? I tried as follows: I tried all the possible chunks of length $2$ containing a $6$, and they all failed because after a few steps they each reduce to a chunk of 1. Then I started trying chunks of length $3$; I tried reducing the ammount of possibilities, but I still had hundreds to check.

Comment: I simply started by considering a sequence of two equal digits and tested whether a cyclic behaviour containing $6$ appears.  For instance, I tested $44$, $16$, $6$, then $55$, $25$, $10$, $1$, then $66$, $36$, $18$, $8$. None of them allowed any cycle.  I arrived to $88$, $64$, $24$, $8$, which suggested that $888$ could be a good choice.

Comment: Why did you begin with two equal digits, instead of any digits?

Comment: Because the end of the cycle is often a single digit (as occurs starting with $88$): having equal initial digits then facilitates the step of passing from the initial sequence of two digits to an initial sequence of three digits (in this case, the step from $88$ to $888$).

Comment: Hmm ok I was taking a totally different approach, I was only considering sequences containing $6$, and trying to narrow down the possibilities if the $6$ was first, second, or third. I don't know if there are any repeating chunks cintaining a $6$ of length $3$, but I wouldve had to move to chunks of length $4$ before I found your example.